# Check cookie with javascript and display colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, colorbox

I have the cookie 'v_regUsr'

When the user goes to my page, I need javascript to check to see if the cookie is there.

If there **is** a cookie there named 'v_regUsr' then the page should just load up normally

If there **isn't** a cookie there named 'v_regUsr' then I need a call to the colorbox.

I just don't know where to put this code:

```
$.colorbox({width:"480px",height:"480px", inframe:true, href:"test.php"});
```

is it something with "if" and "else" statements?

Answer (score 0):

To do in jQuery, use the **[cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)** like so:

```
alert( $.cookie("v_regUsr") );
```

for modal

```
if (!$.cookie("v_regUsr")) {
    $.colorbox({width:"480px",height:"480px", inframe:true, href:"test.php"});
}
```

Comment: this looks good, but it has to open the colorbox if the cookie is not there

Comment: oh nothing i read that wrong, i want the colorbox to sow if the cookie "v_regUsr" does not exist